# Long double precision error saturation in RK integrator

Tags: c, precision, numerical-methods, runge-kutta, long-double

I'm trying to write an integrator which uses long doubles for very high precision.  I know that my system architecture has long double support, but for some reason, the precision of my integrator maxes out at 16 significant digits.  Here's some code which recreates what I'm seeing. The integrator for this example was adapted from [this source](http://www.mymathlib.com/diffeq/embedded_runge_kutta/embedded_fehlberg_3_4.html).  In this test case, I am using it to calculate Euler's number (I apologize for the length of the code block but I can't recreate the behavior any other way):

```c
// ld_int.c: a simple integrator using long doubles
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define max(x,y) ( (x) < (y) ? (y) : (x) )
#define min(x,y) ( (x) < (y) ? (x) : (y) )

#define ATTEMPTS 50


static long double Runge_Kutta(long double (*f)(long double),
                               long double *y,
                               long double x,
                               long double h);

int Embedded_Verner_3_4(long double (*f)(long double),
                        long double y[],
                        long double x,
                        long double h,
                        long double xmax,
                        long double *h_next,
                        long double tolerance);

long double dydx(long double y);


// the only command-line argument to this is the desired precision.
// that is, if you run this with the argument -14, it will give you 
// an answer which is correct to 10^-14
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    long double y0[2] = {1.L, 2.L};
    long double x0 = 0.L;
    long double h = 1e-4L;
    long double xmax = 1L;
    long double tol = powl(10, atoi(argv[1]));
    
    Embedded_Verner_3_4(dydx, y0, x0, h, xmax, &h_next, tol)
    
    // compare a long-double value for E
    printf("expl(1) = %0.22LF\n", expl(1));
    
    // with the calculated value
    printf("eval    = %0.22LF\n", y0[1]);

    return(0);
}

// this test function just returns the input so it integrates e^x
long double dydx(long double y){
    return(y);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Arguments:                                                                //
//     double *f  Pointer to the function which returns the slope at (x,y) of //
//                integral curve of the differential equation y' = f(x,y)     //
//                which passes through the point (x0,y0) corresponding to the //
//                initial condition y(x0) = y0.                               //
//     double y[] On input y[0] is the initial value of y at x, on output     //
//                y[1] is the solution at xmax.                               //
//     double x   The initial value of x.                                     //
//     double h   Initial step size.                                          //
//     double xmax The endpoint of x.                                         //
//     double *h_next   A pointer to the estimated step size for successive   //
//                      calls to Runge_Kutta_Fehlberg.                        //
//     double tolerance The tolerance of y(xmax), i.e. a solution is sought   //
//                so that the relative error < tolerance.                     //
//                                                                            //
//  Return Values:                                                            //
//     0   The solution of y' = f(x,y) from x to xmax is stored y[1] and      //
//         h_next has the value to the next size to try.                      //
//    -1   The solution of y' = f(x,y) from x to xmax failed.                 //
//    -2   Failed because either xmax < x or the step size h <= 0.            //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int Embedded_Verner_3_4(long double (*f)(long double),
                        long double y[],
                        long double x,
                        long double h,
                        long double xmax,
                        long double *h_next,
                        long double tolerance){
   long double scale;
   long double temp_y[2];
   long double err;
   long double yy;
   int i;
   int last_interval = 0;
   long double MIN_SCALE_FACTOR = 0.125L;
   long double MAX_SCALE_FACTOR = 4.0L;

      // Verify that the step size is positive and that the upper endpoint //
      // of integration is greater than the initial enpoint.               //

   if (xmax < x || h <= 0.0) return -2;
       // If the upper endpoint of the independent variable agrees with the //
       // initial value of the independent variable.  Set the value of the  //
       // dependent variable and return success.                            //

   *h_next = h;
   y[1] = y[0];
   if (xmax == x) return 0; 
       // Insure that the step size h is not larger than the length of the //
       // integration interval.                                            //
  
   h = min(h, xmax - x);

        // Redefine the error tolerance to an error tolerance per unit    //
        // length of the integration interval.                            //

   tolerance /= (xmax - x);

        // Integrate the diff eq y'=f(x,y) from x=x to x=xmax trying to  //
        // maintain an error less than tolerance * (xmax-x) using an     //
        // initial step size of h and initial value: y = y[0]            //

   temp_y[0] = y[0];
   while (x < xmax){
      scale = 1.0L;
      for(i = 0; i < ATTEMPTS; i++){
         err = fabsl(Runge_Kutta(f, temp_y, x, h));
         if(err == 0.0L){
             scale = MAX_SCALE_FACTOR;
             break;
         }
         yy = (temp_y[0] == 0.0L)?
                tolerance:
                fabsl(temp_y[0]);

         scale = 0.8L * powl(tolerance * yy / err, 0.2L);
         scale = min(max(scale,MIN_SCALE_FACTOR), MAX_SCALE_FACTOR);    
         
         if(err < (tolerance * yy))
            break;
         
         h *= scale;
         
         if(x + h > xmax){
             h = xmax - x;
         }

         else if(x + h + 0.5L * h > xmax){
             h = 0.5L * h;
         }
        
      }
      
      if(i >= ATTEMPTS){
          printf("\nout of attempts. stats:\nerr = %LF, h = %LF, scale = %LF, x = %LF\n\n", log10l(err), log10l(h), scale, x);
          *h_next = h * scale;
          return -1;
      }
      
      temp_y[0] = temp_y[1];         
      x += h;
      h *= scale;
      *h_next = h;
      
      if(last_interval)
          break;
      
      if(x + h > xmax){
          last_interval = 1;
          h = xmax - x;
      }
      
      else if(x + h + 0.5 * h > xmax)
          h = 0.5 * h;
   }
   y[1] = temp_y[1];
   return 0;
}

static const long double a2 = 2.0 / 7.0;
static const long double a3 = 7.0 / 15.0;
static const long double a4 = 35.0 / 38.0;

static const long double b31 = 77.0 / 900.0;
static const long double b32 = 343.0 / 900.0;
static const long double b41 = 805.0 / 1444.0;
static const long double b42 = -77175.0 / 54872.0;
static const long double b43 = 97125.0 / 54872.0;
static const long double b51 = 79.0 / 490.0;
static const long double b53 = 2175.0 / 3626.0;
static const long double b54 = 2166.0 / 9065.0;

static const long double c1 = 229.0 / 1470.0;
static const long double c3 = 1125.0 / 1813.0;
static const long double c4 = 13718.0 / 81585.0;
static const long double c5 = 1.0 / 18.0;

static const long double d1 = -888.0 / 163170.0;
static const long double d3 = 3375.0 / 163170.0;
static const long double d4 = -11552.0 / 163170.0;
static const long double d5 = 9065.0 / 163170.0;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Arguments:                                                                //
//     double *f  Pointer to the function which returns the slope at (y) of //
//                integral curve of the differential equation y' = f(y)     //
//                which passes through the point (x0,y[0]).                   //
//     double y[] On input y[0] is the initial value of y at x, on output     //
//                y[1] is the solution at x + h.                              //
//     double x   Initial value of x.                                         //
//     double h   Step size                                                   //
//                                                                            //
//  Return Values:                                                            //
//     This routine returns the err / h.  The solution of y(x) at x + h is    //
//     returned in y[1].  
///////////////////////////////////////
static long double Runge_Kutta(long double (*f)(long double),
                               long double *y,
                               long double x0,
                               long double h){
       
    long double k1, k2, k3, k4, k5;
    long double h2 = a2 * h;

    k1 = (*f)(*y);
    k2 = (*f)(*y + h2 * k1);
    k3 = (*f)(*y + h * ( b31*k1 + b32*k2) );
    k4 = (*f)(*y + h * ( b41*k1 + b42*k2 + b43*k3) );
    k5 = (*f)(*y + h * ( b51*k1 + b53*k3 + b54*k4) );
    *(y+1) = *y +  h * (c1*k1 + c3*k3 + c4*k4 + c5*k5);
    return  d1*k1 + d3*k3 + d4*k4 + d5*k5;
}
```

I compile this code with

```
$ gcc -c ld_int.c
$ gcc ld_int.o -lm -o ldint
```

and running it with

```
$ ./ldint -16
```

will return

```
expl(1) = 2.7182818284590452354282
eval    = 2.7182818284590453085034
```

where the two values of E agree to the 16th decimal place.
However, when I try to go to higher order, with `./ldt -17`, for example, it suddenly can't converge.  If you have the integrator print the error for every step, you see it hovers around 10^-16.8, but the timestep will go to 0 before the error ever gets below 10^-17.  This sounds to me like it's still getting saturated at double precision, despite my doing my best to make everything in the code a long double.

Again, I apologize for the amount of code in the above block, but it really doesn't reproduce any other way that I can figure out.  I wrote a test function to calculate E through its Taylor expansion instead, and it was completely happy to calculate it to 19 significant figures with long doubles.  I can't figure out what's special about the integration case.

Comment: What kind of system do you have?  On some, `long double` is actually the same as `double`.

Comment: The precision of `long double` is roughly 19 digits. If the algorithm needs some precision leeway, it's expected that it will behave badly when getting close to 19. For example in your `Runge_Kutta`, you add the step to y: for y=e0 and step=e-6, this will discard 6 digits, bringing the precision of step to e-13. If the algorithm needed more than 13 digits precision to get your 17 digit results, it will fail. From what I checked here the algorithm tries with smaller steps, which discards even more precision. At some point step gets lower than e-19 and `Runge_Kutta` doesn't work anymore at all.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using an x87 platform and `long double` is 80-bit. If you try on an ARM platform it should be 128-bit.

Comment: @NateEldredge - It's on an x87 platform, and printing the output of `sizeof(long double)` returns `16`.

Comment: @ElderBug - Yes, I am on x87, and it's an 80 bit `long double`.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to an ARM machine, and I would need it to run on a specific cluster node anyway.

Comment: ARM64's 128-bit `long double` is entirely software emulated anyway.  If you want software 128-bit floats on x86, you can use gcc's `__float128`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but for some reason, the precision of my integrator maxes out at 16 significant digits.

At a minimum, use more correct values of `long double` initialization with `long double` quotients rather than `double` quotients.

```
// long double a2 = 2.0 / 7.0;
long double a2 = 2.0L / 7.0L;
```

Like-wise for the other 19 initializations.

Comment: David, note that `Embedded_Verner_3_4()` function comment header is written with `double` where it should be `long double`.